# Passing struct pointer through a function then accessing struct data

Tags: c

I'm working on a function that works as part of a larger program. My C pointer skills are a bit rusty and so I need some help here.

**Notice:** I've omitted a lot of the program because it is irrelevant and works correctly, all you need to know is that I import a header file that declares the struct `ImportedStruct`, also, I **cannot** change the function header, so I need to pass the ImportedStruct as a pointer and the function as a pointer.

I get the following error message in VS code: `pointer to incomplete class type is not allowed`.

Any ideas?

```
#include "name.h"
long int *functionName(struct ImportedStruct *structName, int *irrelevant){
    int width = structName->width;
    int height = structName->height;

    // Remaining function ...
}
```

Header file:

```
struct ImportedStruct 
{ 
  int width, height;
};
```

Comment: Are you sure you included the header? Also, `ImportedStruct` -> `structName`.

Comment: My apologies, @Neil I had a typo. I just edited the code, thanks for the heads up!

Comment: Also, I'm sure I imported the header correctly, as otherwise I would have had other errors indicating that "ImportedStruct" is not a valid type. But it is in this case, the only problem is that it's not working when I use pointers.

Comment: That should work, now.

Comment: Actually, the typo was in stackoverflow only, not in my IDE. It still doesn't work unfortunately.

Comment: Is the error line number the definition of the function?

Comment: @Iyad: You actually wouldn't get an error that it's not a valid type. You'd get the error that you got, that the type is not defined. The compiler knows that `struct ImportedStruct` is a type, it has the keyword struct in front of it.

Comment: Ah yes you're right Bill. But I believe that I've imported the header file correctly. What else could the problem be?

Comment: @BillLynch `struct Undeclared *` is legal in C89, but C99 compilers should give (at least) a warning, I think.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I just compiled the code you provide

```
struct ImportedStruct 
{ 
  int width, height;
};

long int *functionName(struct ImportedStruct *structName, int *irrelevant){
    int width = structName->width;
    int height = structName->height;

    // Remaining function ...
    return (long int *)(width + height);
}
```

and it compiled successfully.

Make sure struct definition is included.
Also, you can put

```
struct ImportedStruct 
{ 
  int width, height;
};
```

right before your function definition. If compiler does not give you `multiple definition` error, then struct definition is not included by headers.

Comment: Hi Tarek, thank you for your answer. I've just edited my code segment. Can you take a look again?

Comment: Hi @lyad. Edited the answer. Please check if helps.

Comment: Hi Tarek, thank you so much for your help. You're right, when I compile it with your edits it does work properly. The problem is, I'm importing that struct from another header file. Which I believe I've imported properly (`include "name.h"`) at the top. Do you have any idea what else it could be? Because I need to import the struct and not re-declare it.

Comment: It would help if we could see a minimal example of code that has this error.

Comment: Just track the headers you include that they actually include the header with `ImportedStruct` definition. It also could be that definition is protected by preprocessor defines.

Comment: I'll be honest, I'm very confused. I just copied and pasted all the files into a new directory and it magically worked. Could this be a VS code bug or what?
Thanks for all your help everyone!

Comment: The existence of the word 'class' in the original error messages suggests to me that you tried to compile it as C++